# Difference between force.com site and site.com?

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

I have recently gone through site.com and understand a few steps of creating websites.  Now my question is: How is site.com different from a force.com site in end user perspective?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Resolution
**Force.com Sites:**

- Force.com sites supports both authenticated and public websites (i.e. the legacy portal products).
- Included in all Enterprise Edition (or above) and Developer orgs.
- Support for custom pages using Visualforce, JavaScript, CSS.
- Main target audience is for users that are developers familiar with the above languages.
- Can access all Force.com objects.
- A full review of the product is available on **[this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Sites)**.

**Site.com:**

- Formerly called "Siteforce".
- Is a provisioned (paid-for) product.
- Site.com is meant for non-technical administrators as there is no coding necessary.
- Drag n drop support for CMS.
- Allows custom coding using HTML, CSS, Javascript.
- Includes a security model of who can contribute to and publish sites.
- Chatter supported for contribution of content while chatter is not available on the front end website.
- A full review of the product is available on **[this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Site.com)**.

Answer (score 7):

For the *end user*, there may be no noticeable difference between a site created via Force.com Sites or in Site.com.

For *developers and content managers*, the two are very different:

- **Site.com** is a CMS (Content Management System) that allows developers and non-developers alike to maintain a website. It has WYSIWYG editing and point-and-click page creation and management. Underlying Salesforce functionality is fairly constrained.
- **Force.com Sites** are websites that are created and coded by developers using Visualforce (an html-like SFDC-view language) and apex code. Nearly every imaginable element of Salesforce functionality is available through code that can be written as part of a Force.com Site.

Comment: Just FYI: There is no capital F in Salesforce, nor Visualforce. And Apex is not an all-caps word. http://na13.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_pubs_style_guide.pdf