# Best practice for developing large number of webpages on Site.com or Force.com Sites?

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

We have a requirement to build around 50K pages consuming 60GB of space. What would be the best approach, `Site.com` or `Force.com Sites`?

Comment: why do you know that you will consume 60 GB of space? How many visitors are expected?

Comment: @ChristianDeckert - I do not have an answer to the number of users, it's obviously is much large as we have to migrate 3 applications or build 50k pages and the requirements is to scale up 100gb of space. The applications will essentially be used as CMS with large files.

Comment: You should talk to your sales rep about migrating 60 GB of data. there is a bandwidth limit of 40 gb in 24 h. and 60 GB of data are a bit expensive.

Comment: Pricing is not a concern, could you help if building 50k pages are possible with Site.com or Force.com Sites? We could probably leverage something else for the data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, as already discussed in the commends. There are a lot of considerations to make:

**Considerations**

1. Is Salesforce CRM the right system to manage 50k of pages? (Maybe there is a way to get it managed by using Salesforce Heroku..)
2. Please consider bandwidth limits and storage limits.

**Solution**

In general it is possible to build a site based on salesforce. In my opinion it makes sense to implement such a system using force.com sites, because it is much more flexible.

In order to reduce the bandwidth you should use external services to store assets there. (e.g. Amazon s3)

**Comparison between force.com Sites and site.com**

Has wrote a short comparison of Force.com Sites and Site.com [@ase](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23252/difference-between-force-com-site-and-site-com?rq=1)

> Resolution
>   **Force.com Sites:**
>
> - Force.com sites supports both authenticated and public websites (i.e. the legacy portal products).
> - Included in all Enterprise Edition (or above) and Developer orgs.
> - Support for custom pages using Visualforce, JavaScript, CSS.
> - Main target audience is for users that are developers familiar with the above languages.
> - Can access all Force.com objects.
> - A full review of the product is available on **[this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Sites)**.
>
> **Site.com:**
>
> - Formerly called "Siteforce".
> - Is a provisioned (paid-for) product.
> - Site.com is meant for non-technical administrators as there is no coding necessary.
> - Drag n drop support for CMS.
> - Allows custom coding using HTML, CSS, Javascript.
> - Includes a security model of who can contribute to and publish sites.
> - Chatter supported for contribution of content while chatter is not available on the front end website.
> - A full review of the product is available on **[this page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Site.com)**.

Comment: Yes, I have all those in mind as Plan B :-) using Heroku.  We definitely intend to leverage AWS services or similar PaaS platform for storage purpose. Was wondering if go to market and maintenance would be easier with which of these 3 options (1) site.com (2) force.com sites (3) heroku assuming we have the skill sets for all 3.

Comment: (don't use site.com in case of over 50k pages, there is no way to maintain the website.) My suggestion is to use force.com Sites in case you can make sure that the transferred data is less than 40 gb in 24 h.